# required field validator not working for ajax html editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to check if html editor is empty or not. .

```
 <cc:HtmlEditor ID="Editor" 
               runat="server" 
               Height="500px" 
               Width="700px" Visible="false" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqEditor" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Editor" ErrorMessage="Body Can't be empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But it's not validating the edior. .

Plz help me!

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Your HtmlEditor visibility is hidden so that will not be rendered to the output and validation will be ignored.